# Want to Connect to PostgreSQL with pgAdmin but not able to figure out credentials from the String

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Maybe a stupid question, I have the Following String received from my college, I have installed the PG admin and I need to provide the credentials such as username password, DB Name, and Port.

```
postgresql://aaaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbb@cccccc-development.ddddddd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/eeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

I would like to know what is the credentials here such as username and password to connect to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, Here is the breakdown of the Connection String.

**Connection String:** postgresql://aaaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbb@cccccc-development.ddddddd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/eeeeeeeeeeeeee

The above Sring can be broken down into the following:

- **Host:** cccccc-development.ddddddd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
- **Port:** 5432
- **Database Name:** eeeeeeeeeeeeee
- **username:** aaaaaaaaa
- **Password:** bbbbbbbb

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. This is exactly what i was looking for. I was able to connect to PostgreSQL with pgAdmin